# NSTableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:) causes wrong subview layout when usesAutomaticRowHeights = true

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, appkit

I have a table view where each row has two labels, one left-aligned and one right-aligned. I would like to reload a single row, but doing so causes the right-aligned label to hug the left-aligned label.

Before the reload:

[image]

After the reload:

[image]

Reloading the whole table view instead, or disabling automatic row height, solves the issue. Can a single row be reloaded without resorting to these two workaround?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate {
    
    override func loadView() {
        let tableView = NSTableView()
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.usesAutomaticRowHeights = true
        let column = NSTableColumn()
        column.width = 400
        tableView.addTableColumn(column)
        let scrollView = NSScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.documentView = tableView
        view = scrollView
        
        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { _ in
            print("reload")
            tableView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: IndexSet(integer: 2), columnIndexes: IndexSet(integer: 0))
//            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return 5
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let cell = NSTableCellView()
        let textField1 = NSTextField(labelWithString: "hello")
        textField1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let textField2 = NSTextField(wrappingLabelWithString: "world")
        textField2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        textField2.alignment = .right
        let stack = NSStackView(views: [
            textField1,
            textField2
        ])
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.distribution = .fill
        cell.addSubview(stack)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([stack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.topAnchor, constant: 0), stack.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.leadingAnchor, constant: 0), stack.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: 0), stack.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.trailingAnchor, constant: 0)])
        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, the constraints between the cell view and row view are missing. Try hiding and unhiding the row.

Comment: Hiding and unhiding seems to be a workaround, although one still needs to keep track of the selection and restore it afterwards, as hiding a row deselects it.